# Socket server: should provide shell like interface

Tags: java, sockets, command-line-interface, serversocket

I have web server implemented using sockets (build a directory list service).

I am not sure how to  provide a text (shell‐like) interface.

This is basically required since user can type in commands in order to invoke the appropriate server actions like view all files shared by user and so on.

If the server is already running how do we combine the command line interface with this server.

Can anyone please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide web-based command line access (which I don't recommend unless it's secure) then you need to use some kind of server-side scripting interface.

You could use CGI to execute the commands, or you could send them to a php script which could execute them. I haven't tried the former, but the latter is fairly easy.

Answer (score 0):

Listen on a different socket (not using http) and use telnet to connect.